# String or binary data would be truncated nchar

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in which I am trying to update a `nchar(60)` column with a `varchar(50)` variable. It works fine when the variable length <= 30, but I am getting an error

> String or binary data would be truncated

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without changing table structure? and why nvarchar(100) instead of varchar(50)

Comment: The error occurs because you try to store more than 60 characters but don't realize it. It's impossible to help though without the actual code and table schema. You do realize though, that `nchar(xxx)` is a fixed-length field? If you try to add 30 characters to an `nchar(40)` field for example, you end up with 70 characters always

Comment: @gofr1 changing the field size won't solve any problems. It may hide it for a while or may actually make it *worse*, if eg, the OP is using the original value for string manipulations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yeah, you are right, I will delete this comment

Comment: No, I meant that adding 30 to an nchar(40) field would result in 70 characters. The OP's problem occurs when passing a parameter over 30 characters long. That, and the use of `nchar(60)` instead of `nvarchar(60)` suggest the OP probably doesn't understand that `nchar` is fixed-length and is trying to use string manipulations that result in a value over 60 characters long

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for the code it is simple, the variable is a parameter in a stored procedure. The ps is called from c# code

Comment: Post the code otherwise it's impossible to guess what it does wrong. The error is crystal clear. You are trying to store more than 60 characters on a 60 character field. Why? Only your code shows